# Setting Rails Checkbox from Another Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a checkbox that belongs to "Foo" class.  I have another "Preferences" class that sets the default for what that checkbox should be.

I tried using

```
f.check_box :email_preference, :value => preferences.email_preference
```

but it doesn't work.  I use this page to do new record creation as well as edit, so obviously for new records I would want to take the preferences.email_preference setting as a default, then for editing the record use the foo.email_preference.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Hey there Kevin, are you trying to set this in a form? Are these models associated? Give us a little functionality context. There are lots of different ways to implement this sort of functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Try Following

```
check_box_tag :preference, :email_preference, :value => preferences.email_preference
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
value = @foo.new_record? ? preferences.email_preference : @foo.email_preference

f.check_box :email_preference, :value => value
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing this in the wrong place.  The view shouldn't care about the preferences class.  When a new Foo is created, it should set the value of :email_preference on the object, and then the view will simply display the result of this.

I forget the name of the constructor method on ActiveRecord classes, or if there is a callback to leverage here.  I'll look it up.